# CSS Grid Infinite Scrolling and Dynamic Contents

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

I am about to implement a template with **css grid** 
see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/
or this nice article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

But I have to define the grid rows and columns in the css, so I was wondering how this layout will behave with dynamic content like for example infinite scrolling.
Or an ajax request that modify the number of elements.

If I have to load new rows is there a way to use only css grids? And is that reasonable?
I wonder what is the best way to mix css grids with flex layouts, or bootstrap structure.

Answer (score 0):

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/page-layout/hero-image-panel/

```
grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
```